Proof that $\mathbb{B}^{n}$ is not homogenous
So, let be:
$$\mathbb{B}^{n}=\{x\in \mathbb{R}^{n}\mid \lVert x\rVert \leq 1\}$$
I want to show that $\mathbb{B}^{n}$ is not homogenous. My attempt is suppose that in fact it is and then some how use Brouwer Fixed Point Theorem on $\mathbb{B}^{n}$ to get some contradiction. But I don't know whats else do... Maybe use that the group of homeomorphisms of $\mathbb{B}^{n}$ ($\mathscr{H}(\mathbb{B}^{n})$) acts in a transitive way on $\mathbb{B}^{n}$, I've also see that Burnside Lemma could be usefull but $\mathscr{H}(\mathbb{B}^{n})$ is not finite.
Thanks for help.

Do you know the invariance of domain theorem?

Well, yes but i dont get how to use it in this case...

Homogeneity requires that, in a sense, all points "look the same" locally (i.e. have homeomorphic neighbourhoods). Consider regions of $B^n$ that fail this check, and therefore would be incompatible were you to try form a homeomorphism mapping one to the other. Invariance of domain theorem will provide the machinery for the proof once you know how to begin.

So for example, take $x\in B^{n}$ such $||x||=1$ and considere a homeomorphism h thath send $\overline{0}$ to x? Maybe in that way I can proof that $h[B(\overline{0},1)]$ is not open.

@YvesStanislasSH Exactly - homeomorphisms are open maps, but your proposed map cannot be so. You may not even need invariance of domain.

With the invariance of domain theorem, this is a 1-sentence proof.

Wich versión you have of the theorem?

There is no homeomorphism mapping a point $x \in \partial \mathbb B^n = S^{n-1}$ to $0$.
Assume to the contrary that such a homeomorphism exists. Then $\mathbb B^n \setminus \{x\}$ and $\mathbb B^n \setminus \{0\}$ would be homeomorphic, hence homotopy equivalent. But $\mathbb B^n \setminus \{x\}$  is contractible (take the radial deformation to $0$) and $\mathbb B^n \setminus \{0\} \simeq S^{-1}$ is not contractible, a contradiction.
